# How to handle keystroke in python socket?

Tags: python, sockets, interactive, keystroke

I am writing a socket based "python `cmd` like" server module which can support cli interactive functions such as autocompletion or command history, by doing that a simple "`telnet`" or "`nc`" client side may able to connect to server to read/set something on server side.

after searching, there are a lot of modules can do "cmd" part such like python standard module "`cmd`" or "`ipython`" or even vty simulator, however, I cannot find a module can actually bind to socket directly to detect keystrokes such as "`tab`" key or "`control+c`" client side. Most of them just able to process line(s) read, which not suitable for autocompletion with tab press or command history with up/down press.

I think this question can be simplify to:

**Is that possible to read socket keystroke input non-blocking, then process this key input value somehow server side - for example ASCII code + 1, then echo back to socket to show in client side?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: After searching, telnet or ssh can NOT working on pure socket layer but with standard protocol layer, which I was misunderstood before.

rfc855 and rfc4253 defined how telnet/ssh works, just for someone have same concern, in my case, i need to use twisted or write layer my own.
 
Many thanks Hans to point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible. As you say, you want to write a socket based `cmd` like server. The server will open a socket and listen for data from the client. Now it is possible to read socket input character by character (which is not the same as non-blocking BTW), but that will not help you.

It is up to the client program to decide how and when to send the data. So if the client side program decides to "eat" tab and control characters, then you will simply not see them. So if you want to process keystrokes one by one, you will also need a client application.

Comment: I see, so, how do common systems handle telnet/ssh access? For example, to use "telnet" in windows to telnet a linux box, the shell can have keystrock detection?

Comment: telnet and ssh have both a client and a server side. The individual keystrokes are captured in the client and then sent to the server. So, to do what you want, you will need a client application. What you might try to do is simply use `telnet` as your client application and connect telnet to your socket server.